# Spring profile not properly applied to tests involving @Configurable

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aspectj, spring-test

I have a very weird situation, that has happened in several systems already. I am using Spring Boot and AspectJ CTW to `@Autowired` dependencies in some entities (instanciated outside the container).

The class that receives dependencies (an abstract entity) some times receive the dependency without applying the profile (configured by `@ActiveProfile` in my test class). It is not deterministic, since by changing how tests are executed different outputs can happen. To illustrate the situation with code:

**The entity**

```
@Configurable
public class AbstractMongoDocument<T> implements Persistable<T> {
    @Transient
    private transient MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
//entity stuff
}
```

**One of the failing tests**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = LOVApplication.class)
@ActiveProfiles("local-test")
public class MyCrazyIntegrationTest {

    @Test
    public void filterByFieldsFullMatchShouldReturnResult() throws Exception {
        //Given
        Location l1 = new Location("name","code",new GeoJsonPoint(11,10));
        l1.save(); //Hence the need of autowiring there.

        //When: whatever
        //Then: Some assertions
    }
}
```

There are some facts that I find very disturbing here:

1. *The dependency is always injected*, but *some times* it apparently **comes from an AppCtx with the default profile**.
2. If it fails for 1 test in 1 class, it behaves the same for all the tests in that particular class.
3. It may or may not happen depending on how you execute that class (At the moment it fails only if I run all the tests, but succeed if I run that class in isolation, it also behaves differently in maven).
4. If I debug it, I can see that the dependency injected didn't get the proper profile. (I discovered that by injecting `ApplicationContext` and surprisingly discovering that it was a different object than the one I received in my tests).
5. What worries me the most, is that now I am not sure if this situation could also happen for non-test environments with for example a Production profile, which would imply a catastrophe.

I have tried to look for open bugs in Jira and I found nothing, so I don't discard I am misconfiguring something. Any help or ideas would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Apparently the situation happens if other test is executed before, with no profile at all. Unfortunately @DirtiesContext didn't resolve this issue completely. Although applying the same profile to all the tests made this problem disappear (but that is not an option).

Comment: There is definitely a BUG with AspectJ autowired dependencies and swapping profiles while testing, I will report it to Jira.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you are experiencing typically should **not** happen in a production deployment; however, it *is* a known issue with integration test suites that load multiple `ApplicationContexts` utilizing `@Configurable` and AspectJ load-time weaving.

For details, see the following issues in Spring's issue tracker:

- https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-6353
- https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-6121

Comment: After some empirical tests, I already realized this was test specific, and was related with AspectJ. Having said that I really appreciate your links, since I was unable to find already reported bugs.

Comment: I'll give your answer as correct since you're highlighting a proper reference to the actual problem. Thank you so much Sam.

Comment: You're welcome, José! FYI: I changed the title in order to help anyone else with similar problems find this issue.